# Type Casting in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, casting

can someone please tell me whether this is the correct way of doing type casting in objective c.

I have an object "myObject" which could possibly be an instance of "DataViewController".
If so i should call the "updateView" method.

```
if (myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(updateView:)])
{
    [(DataViewController *)myObject updateView:data];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a cast in this case: since you've started down the selector path, you might as well call `performSelector:withObject:` for consistency:

```
if (myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(updateView:)]) {
    [myObject performSelector:@selector(updateView:) withObject:data];
}
```

This is a more general approach, because it lets you run `updateView` on objects of other types, not necessarily of `DataViewController`, as long as they have the appropriate method.

If you would like to use a type-based solution, you could use `isKindOfClass:` method, like this:

```
if (myObject isKindOfClass:[DataViewController class]]) {
    DataViewController *ctrl = (DataViewController)myObject;
    [ctrl updateView:data];
}
```